# Using graphics from others' publications

Tags: copyright

I don't know the correct forum to ask this, but if I am doing research and find a very nice graphic I would like to use in my paper, can I cut and paste and cite?

Comment: I had a similar question a time ago: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7238/how-to-cite-a-rebuilt-graphic I think academia is the right place to ask this.

Comment: You should have the permission of the owner.

Comment: I believe that this belongs to Academia.SE, and I think that there'll be more than one question about this already ;)

Comment: @schmendrich This is not true in most cases. You should have the permission of _the copyright holder_, which is usually the publisher. But this really is a discussion for a different site.

Comment: @tohecz This is what I meant